# Instance_eval block not supplied?

Tags: ruby, rack, instance-eval

Does anybody know what's causing this error? I'm trying to make a basic rack application.

`App.rb =>`

```
class Cherry
    class << self
        def app &block
            Cherry::Application.new &block
        end
    end

    class Application
        def initialize &block
            instance_eval &block
        end

        def print_start_message
            puts "Starting server"
        end

        def call env
            [200, {"Content-type" => "text/plain"}, "Hello World"]
        end
   end
end
```

`Config.ru =>`

```
   require 'app'

   run Cherry.app do
        print_start_message
   end
```

EDIT: Apparently I forgot to include the error woops:

`/local/www/cherry/lib/app.rb:12:in 'instance_eval': block not supplied (ArgumentError)`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/), …

Comment: … [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/), [Why aren't `do`/`end` and `{}` always equivalent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7487664/), [Wierd imperfection in Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7620804/), and [Passing block into a method - Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/10909496/).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Apparently you need brackets around the `Cherry.app do..` block:

```
run(Cherry.app do
    "Hello World"
end)
```